# Alternative to returning null value

Tags: java

I think is a bad idea to return `null` values so I am looking to an alternative to this.

Here is my code:

```
 public Flight getFlight(String id)    {
      for (Flight f : this.flightList ) {
         if ( f.getId().equals(id))
            return f;
      }
      return null;
   }
```

I am looking for a certain Flight with a certain id and I want to return it.

If I return `null` I have to check every time if the object I returned is null or not. And I would like to avoid this if possible.

So any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could return an `Optional<Flight>` but you would still have to check that the optional contains a value...

Comment: Well what do you want to happen when a flight doesn't exist for a given `id`? What's your business logic in that case? At some point you need to check whether or not the flight was retrieved successfully.

Comment: I think you're too focused on the "not checking null" part and too little on what you actually imagine your code would look like. You'll always have to check for `null`, whether it has a value (`Optional`) or whether an exception is thrown.

Comment: This question is too broad without context of your app - we have no idea how `getFlight` is called, like... Is in your business domain? Maybe `throw new Exception("flight doesnt exists"); //this will be very slow, but fail-fast` or `return new Flight(null);`? Or `Flight f = new Flight(); flightList.Add(f); return f;`? Or `public bool tryGetFlight(String id, Flight out){return ((out = getFlight()) == null);}` or... So many possibilities, but we dont know how you expect it to work.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526

Comment: dres, @Kayaman is correct:   you need to first decide what behavior you desire in a business context.   What does it **mean** that `getFlight()` was called for a non-existent flight?

Answer (score 3):

This really depends if the event "a flight was not found" is considered exceptional or not.

When you call this method, if the calling code *expects* a valid flight all the time then not finding it is exceptional. There *should* be a flight but there isn't one. In this scenario, it is best to throw a custom Exception like `FlightNotFoundException`, that contains the id of the searched flight. It would typically be a `RuntimeException`: the flight should have been there, there is nothing you can do to recover from this.

However, if this requirement is not met, I don't see anything wrong with returning `null`, as long as this is correctly documented.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Null object pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/null_object_pattern.htm) (in C# is implemented as `string.Empty`), since it

> replaces check of NULL object instance. Instead of putting if check for a null value, Null Object reflects a do nothing relationship. Such Null object can also be used to provide default behaviour in case data is not available.

In your case it could be something like:

```
public class NullFlight extends AbstractFlight {

 @Override
   public String getId() {
      return "Not Available for null Flight!";
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isNil() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Also this is a [valid case](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59) when dealing with [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html), you should return 'new' empty ones instead of Null.

Answer (score 0):

Generally returning null instead of an object is a bad practice. There are two alternatives to returning null.
Fistly I would recommend to check out  [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) with defined neutral ("null") behavior.
The second idea is to thrown your own Exception when you can't return an object.

`if ( f.getId().equals(id)){
            return f;
 }else  throw new FlightNotFoundException();`

Comment: Maybe, I was writing by heart, just to show the case. I narrowed my example, hoping It won't confuse.